# iOS - Change PageControl indicator of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I would like to change dot indicator to Segmented control. Is it possible? And how? I know that I can customize dots like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    ...
}
```

But I want it change for whole new control. If it isn't possible than what would be to best way to create same UIPageController with UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll but with Segmented control? Thanks

Comment: Try with custom UIPageControl.

Comment: You mean create custom class which inherits from UIPageControl right? It wouldn't be problem but how can I set it as default UIPageControl?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26961456/3985749

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution available:

[Is there a way to change page indicator dots color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409319/is-there-a-way-to-change-page-indicator-dots-color)

Instead of creating UIPageControl object create GreyPageControl object. Other things are as it is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to create custom UIPageControl it's clear and thanks for this. But I don't know how to use it with UIPageViewController. I don't create UIPageControl. It's created by using `self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];` and I can modify it in AppDelegate but just colors with code I shown in question.

Comment: In the code you given in question you are using UIPageControl, so rather using that, use GreyPageControl

Comment: It's code that could change colors of UIPageControl but I just get it and I don't assign it to UIPageViewController. If I try `GrayPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];` it doesn't change anything.

Comment: GrayPageControl *pageControl = [GrayPageControl appearance];

Comment: It doesn't help. The example of code is like in this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/ in customize page indicator section.